# Globally change path of assigned macros when using .xlam files

Tags: excel, vba, ribbon, excel-addins

I have a suite of macros which I save in an **.xlam** file for easy transport to other users, which is saved at **C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AddIns**. I also export a ribbon containing a customised menu and icons to which I have assigned the macros.

What I cannot find is a way to update the path in the assigned macros. In this case the ribbon holds the old path with my name as the user. I then have to reassign the macros, one by one, with the new path when I would like to just globally change the **(User)** name. I may be missing something obvious but any workarounds or suggestions would help.

Comment: You can integrate a customized ribbon with an XLAM file. This way, the ribbon will automatically be available whenever users load the XLAM add-in, eliminating the need for users to import a separate ribbon configuration file. Additionally, the location of the XLAM add-in won't pose any issues.

Comment: Don't you use "OfficeRibbonXEditor" co customize the ribbon you need to appear **only when the add-in is loaded**? Then, what do you mean by "update the path in the assigned macros"? What path do you use to be add-in location dependent? If custom icons, you can place them on the add-in (hidden) sheet and bring them from there. Then, an add-in can be located anywhere in the computer. Not necessarily to be placed on `\Microsoft\AddIns` path... Is it something I am missing? Can you give an example of used "path in the assigned macros"?

Comment: @FaneDuru I hadn't used the 'OfficeRibbonEditor' as I was not aware of it. Also, I was associating the macros the wrong way when I used the .xlam file so had this problem with the pathing.  I've overcome this by opening up the .xlam file and creating the customised menu.  However, for transporting the .xlam file to other users, I've downloaded the ribbon editor and successfully created an .xlm schema to work with my ribbon. My problem now is to resize images I've saved for the individual macros as windows seems to reduce them in size.